# Drawing using CGContextRef

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I am trying to create an application where I can write. I have progressed in that by using CGContextRef. I have written a following code.

```
previousPoint2 = previousPoint1;
previousPoint1 = [touch previousLocationInView:m_secondaryDrawingImgeView];
currentPoint = [touch locationInView:m_secondaryDrawingImgeView];
// calculate mid point
CGPoint mid1 = [self midPoint:previousPoint1 :previousPoint2]; 
CGPoint mid2 =[self midPoint:currentPoint :previousPoint1];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(m_secondaryDrawingImgeView.frame.size);
[m_secondaryDrawingImgeView.image drawInRect:
               CGRectMake(0, 0, m_secondaryDrawingImgeView.frame.size.width,
                               m_secondaryDrawingImgeView.frame.size.height)];
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);
// Use QuadCurve is the key
CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context,
        previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y); 
// NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:mid1, nil]
//  NSLog(@"%@",color);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context,m_width);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
m_secondaryDrawingImgeView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

When I set opacity to my color it shows dots in line, which I want to remove.

Is it the right path i am going on?
Is there any way i can remove those dots?

Attaching images for more clarity. What is happening after writing this code is image-1 and what i want is image-2

[image]
[image]

Comment: means you want to give effect like 2nd image?

Comment: May be [this link](http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=132024) helps you.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.But it is also not working when i set opacity of color it is giving me same result.

Comment: Yes sarah i want to give effect like second image

Comment: yes. can you tell me if i want to set opacity of color how do i set that? I am setting alpha value in color.(a from rgba)

Comment: you may have set color alpha value 1 always. if you get any hint plz let me know

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6349/discussion-between-prajakta-kulkarni-and-sarah)

Comment: fine. I also tested it with less alpha value and it results into image2 output. Let me try the same with some other scenario.

Comment: gr8 can you share your code with me?

Comment: i just had to implement the same functionality and hence just took the class as it is. so you can see my code in the same project :(

Comment: please send me the color line where you have set alpha for color

Comment: CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, .50);

Comment: Thanks :),But am not getting why it is not working at my end. i have downloaded the code from that link. and changed line that you have given me.

Comment: As I told you,it is also not working for me. I have taken alpha as 1 and if I reduce it, it would result in pixels only.

Comment: ohh sorry did not get at first time you said image 2 that is why i got confused.

Comment: oh k. Hope you get your solution. All the best :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I cracked it. you have to set blend mode for this following is the code

```
 CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeCopy);
```

Comment: Thats good.. Now tick your answer as correct and close the post.

Comment: hmm need to wait till tomorrow